how to silence X11 warnings on a headless node
I have a headless server setup, and when I ssh in I get
Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated
Everything still works fine, since there's no X11 data to forward. But is there a way to modify the ssh config on the server to silence this warning?

The default configuration of ssh does not forward X11 information.
X11 authentication is only forwarded if the ssh -X option is used or the ssh configuration (either /etc/ssh/ssh_config or the version in ~/.ssh/) includes ForwardX11 yes otherwise it defaults to no.  And if it is enabled globally, you can disable it with ssh option -x.
Even if those options are on, X11Forwarding must also be on for the remote sshd.
So there are actually 3 places you can disable it, from either end, all three of which are off by default, although sshd may have it enabled in the config file.  Both ends must enable it for it to work.

It is disabled on the server-side in /etc/ssh/sshd_config with
X11Forwarding no.
On the client side, /etc/ssh/ssh_config has
X11Forwarding yes
So, the client's ssh was defaulting to -X. And, indeed, if I ssh in with -x, I don't get an warning.
But, I'm not the only user on this system, and I'd like to configure the server no to emit this warning regardless. Any ideas?

I suspect the client is emitting the warning, not the server.  I would assume disabling forwarding server side would make it go away though.

Ah! I think you're right user10489. I think we can consider this question SOLVED.

One more piece of info for any future readers: As an experiment, I just tried enabling X11 forwarding on the server. It can't actually do this since it doesn't even have X11 installed, but I was still able to log in, and I still got the warning.
